# Error: Expecting rightparen before colon

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on an actionscript and I can'f seem to find the problem on this code block.
Please help.

Partial code:

```
    private function constructCommunicatorAndConnect() : void
    {
        var cHost:* = ExternalData.splashServerHosts[this.m_nSplashServerIndex];
        var nPort:* = int(ExternalData.splashServerPorts[this.m_nSplashServerIndex]);
        var cSocket:* = new ReconnectingStringSocket(cHost, nPort, new RandomXORScrambler(68, 47));
        cSocket.addEventListener(ReconnectingStringSocket.RECONNECTING, function (event:Event) : void
        {
            MultiplayerContainer.addTextToConsole("Lost splash connection, trying to reconnect...");
            return;
        }// end function
        );
        cSocket.addEventListener(ReconnectingStringSocket.RECONNECTING_SUCCESSFUL, function (event:Event) : void
        {
            MultiplayerContainer.addTextToConsole("Splash connection succesfully reestablished");
            return;
        }// end function
        );
        this.m_cSplashCommunicator = new SplashCommunicator(cSocket, MultiplayerContainer.player.com.miniclip.multiplayer.container.player:ILocalPlayer::sessionID, MultiplayerContainer.player.userID, ExternalData.gameID, this);
        this.m_cSplashCommunicator.connect();
        MultiplayerContainer.addTextToConsole("Connecting to splash server #" + this.m_nSplashServerIndex + " (" + cHost + ":" + nPort + ") with session \"" + MultiplayerContainer.player.sessionID + "\"");
        dispatchEvent(new Event(COMMUNICATOR_CONSTRUCTED));
        return;
    }// end function
```

The error is at

```
this.m_cSplashCommunicator = new SplashCommunicator(cSocket, MultiplayerContainer.player.com.miniclip.multiplayer.container.player:ILocalPlayer::sessionID, MultiplayerContainer.player.userID, ExternalData.gameID, this);
```

Some relevant functions:

```
public function SplashCommunicator(param1:StringSocket_i, param2:String, param3:String, param4:String, param5:ISplashListener)
    {
        super(param1, param5);
        param1.setSocketEventHandler(this.handleSocketEvent);
        param1.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, this.socketConnected);
        this.m_cSessionID = param2 != null ? (param2) : ("");
        this.m_cUserID = param3 != null ? (param3) : ("");
        this.m_cGameID = param4;
        this.m_cListener = param5;
        return;
    }// end function
```

Comment: heres your problem "Expecting rightparen before colon"

Answer (score 0):

heres your problem, Check your code

```
     .player:ILocalPlayer::sessionID, Multiplaye // check these ::
      whatever = new whatever(somemorestuff,hi{in here is where you have ::::::::::},outside);
```

See the above pattern the colon is inside the parentheses (MC{x:200,y:200});
Im hoping your following me

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure it out now. I'm very new at AS3.

Comment: So what I did was `MultiplayerContainer.player.{com.miniclip.multiplayer.container.player:ILocalPlayer::sessionID},` But I'm getting more error.

Comment: you got a ".{" thats incorrect the dot before "{" explain what you are doing.use"." for reference to so movieclip.body.x = ?? its hard to explain if i dont know the errors but keep trying

Comment: Now I tried this: `(cSocket, MultiplayerContainer.player{com.miniclip.multiplayer.container.player:ILocalPlayer::sessionID, MultiplayerContainer.player.userID}, `

and I get 4 errors saying sepecting rightparen, rightbrace, identifier before comma, rightbrace.

Comment: Oops. My mistake on the closing bracket.

Comment: your going to have to go through each error try breaking it up, and as suggested if this decompiled then you will have issues aswell

Comment: Yes its decompiled. Just trying it for educational purposes.

Comment: i don't encourage  to de-compile look your best option i think is to tell me what you want to do and i can help you with a new script.i dont mind but you got let me know what you want and whats the goal